# How to loop through a script to let a user selection different options?

Tags: powershell

Fairly new to Powershell. I'm working on a script that will let a user install different pieces of software that will be needed. This process is currently being done manually and it can take 30-45 minutes to install everything that is needed. However, not everything needs to be installed on each workstation so I need flexibility for the user. This is what I have come up with so far. (Modified for brevity)

```
$Software1Path = "Path to installer"
$Software2Path = "Path to installer"
$Software3Path = "Path to installer"


function Software1 {
     $Software1Arguments = "/S"
     Start-Process -FilePath $Software1Installer $Software1Arguments -Wait

     InstallOptions
}

function Software2 {
     $Software2Arguments = "/silent"
     Start-Process -FilePath $Software2Installer $Software2Arguments -Wait

     InstallOptions
}


function Software3 {
     $Software3Arguments = "/passive"
     Start-Process -FilePath $Software3Installer $Software3Arguments -Wait

     InstallOptions
}



function InstallOptions {
    Do {
        Clear-Host

        Write-Host('1. Install Software1')
        Write-Host('2. Install Software1')
        Write-Host('3. Install Software1')
        Write-Host('4. Install All Three')
        Write-Host('0. Exit')
        $value = Read-Host 'Input your selection (0-3)'
        }

     Until ($value -eq "o"){
        switch ($value) {
                "0" {exit}
                "1" { Software 1}
                "2" { Software 2}
                "3" { Software 3}
                "4" { Software1  
                      Software2
                      Software3}
       }
     }

}
```

It does not give the desired result. I can either install one piece of software but then the script exits and I also cannot install all three. I've played with the InstallOptions and wrote it ten different ways but I am still not getting the desired result. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's because you call InstallOptions recursively everytime you install something

Comment: What would be a better way to loop back around to the "menu"?

Comment: well, if i was doing this thing, i'd completely redesign the approach, tbh, no point in trying make this better

Comment: I'm not opposed to rewriting it. I'm fairly new so if you would like to point me to a resource where I can learn to do it differently, I would be happy to study it.

Comment: I think it would be a great idea for you to learn to create a GUI with buttons, that way you wouldn't have to worry about looping back etc, as it would all just be functions, you could have your install function and a switch, and when the user pushes a button it sends the number to the switch which then activates the install. There's a great Lesson on GUI's by foxdeploy: https://foxdeploy.com/2015/04/10/part-i-creating-powershell-guis-in-minutes-using-visual-studio-a-new-hope/ good luck, this is an idea I can see you building on over and over again!

Comment: That is exactly what I had planned. I wanted to get something functional that our team could use now. Once I have it working I want to learn how to create a GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `InstallOptions` in a `while($true) {}` (as long as you keep `0` to exit) or another type of loop to make it return to the menu. If you call the menu from the software installation-function it will never get to 2 and 3 when you use "install all". Try:

```
$Software1Path = "Path to installer"
$Software2Path = "Path to installer"
$Software3Path = "Path to installer"


function Software1 {
     $Software1Arguments = "/S"
     Start-Process -FilePath $Software1Path -ArgumentList $Software1Arguments -Wait
}

function Software2 {
     $Software2Arguments = "/silent"
     Start-Process -FilePath $Software2Path -ArgumentList $Software2Arguments -Wait
}


function Software3 {
     $Software3Arguments = "/passive"
     Start-Process -FilePath $Software3Path -ArgumentList $Software3Arguments -Wait
}



function InstallOptions {
    Clear-Host

    Write-Host('1. Install Software1')
    Write-Host('2. Install Software2')
    Write-Host('3. Install Software3')
    Write-Host('4. Install All Three')
    Write-Host('0. Exit')
    $value = Read-Host 'Input your selection (0-3)'

    switch ($value) {
        "0" {exit}
        "1" { Software1}
        "2" { Software2}
        "3" { Software3}
        "4" { 
            Software1
            Software2
            Software3
            }
       }
}

#Start the train
while($true) { InstallOptions }
```

You might also want to clean this up. Ex. `$Sofware1Path` is outside the function while the `$Software1Arguments` are inside. For simple installations, you could clean this up to use ex. a csv-stored array (can be read stored in a separate file if needed). Something like:

```
$Installations = @(@"
Name,Step,Path,Arguments
Software1,1,"c:\Install Files\Product1\Setup.exe",/S
Software2,2,"c:\Install Files\Product2\SetupPart2.exe",/silent
Software2,1,"c:\Install Files\Product2\Setup.exe","/silent ""space test with ,"""
Software3,1,"c:\Install Files\Product3\Setup.exe",/passive "space test"
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv)


function InstallSoftware ($Name) {
    Write-Host "Installing $Name..."
    $Installations | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $Name } | Sort-Object { $_.Step -as [int] } | ForEach-Object {
        ExecuteStep -Path $_.Path -Arguments $_.Arguments
    }
}

function ExecuteStep ($Path, $Arguments) {
    Write-Host "Executing '$Path' '$Arguments'"
    Start-Process -FilePath $Path -ArgumentList $Arguments -Wait
}

function Menu {
    $UniqueSoftware = $Installations | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Unique | Sort-Object
    $NumOfSoftware = $UniqueSoftware.Count

    #Generate menu
    Clear-Host
    for($i=0;$i -lt $NumOfSoftware; $i++) {
        Write-Host ("{0}. Install {1}" -f ($i+1), $Software[$i].Name)
    }
    Write-Host ("{0}. Install all" -f ($NumOfSoftware+1))
    Write-Host "0. Exit"

    do {
        #Get input
        $value = (Read-Host "Input your selection (0-$($NumOfSoftware+1))") -as [int]

        #Execute
        switch ($value) {
            0 { exit }
            { $_ -gt 0 -and $_ -le $NumOfSoftware } { InstallSoftware -Name $UniqueSoftware[($_-1)] }
            ($NumOfSoftware+1) { 0..($NumOfSoftware-1) | ForEach-Object { InstallSoftware -Name $UniqueSoftware[($_)] } }
            default { Write-Host "Invalid input..." }
        }
    #Validate input or retry
    } until ( $value -ge 0 -and $value -le $NumOfSoftware+1 )

}

#Start the train
while($true) { Menu }
```

Comment: Thank you. I have been building it piece by piece but I definitely see the value in doing it your way as it is much more efficient. I will give it a try and see if it works the way I need it to.

Comment: No problem. If what you have works for you then the simple solution is the fix in the first sample. The other is just an alternative solution that's a little more dynamic, but there a many ways to do it and the right solution depends on the software. Ex. this might not be the best step for complicated install-scripts. I actually updated the alternative solution again to support multiple steps (ordered) to give you an idea for multi-part installations

Comment: Thank you, that is very kind of you. If I don't use it for this script I will definitely use it for a second script that I need. I want to go through it line by line and really understand what it is doing.